# I use ajax submit form data in hapi frame,but the 'request.payload' is {}.why?

Tags: ajax, forms, hapi.js

front end is a form to submit data.

html code of front end:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>page1</title>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'/>
</head>
<body>
<form id='form'>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>people information</legend>
        <label for="name">name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name"/>
        <label for="type">type</label>
        <input type="text" id="type"/>
        <label for="camp">camp</label>
        <input type="text" id="camp"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<button id="commit">提交</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/transdata2.js"></script>
```

I use 'xhr' transfer data from client to server.

js code of front end:

```
var commitBtn = document.querySelector('#commit');

commitBtn.addEventListener('click',function(){
    var form = document.querySelector('#form');
    var vForm = new FormData(form);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 ){
            if(xhr.status == 200){
                console.log(xhr.response);
            } else {

            }
        } else {

        }
    }

    xhr.open('POST','http://localhost:3000/commit');
    xhr.send(vForm);
},false)
```

A simply server code that write by hapi.

hapi code:

```
'use strict';
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({port:3000});

server.start((err) => {
    if(err){
        throw(err);
    }
    console.log('Server running at:',server.info.uri);
});

server.register(require('inert'),(err) => {
    if (err){
        throw err;
    }

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/js/transdata2.js',
        handler:function(request,reply){
            reply.file('./js/transdata2.js');
        }
    })

    server.route({
        method:'GET',
        path:'/page1',
        handler:function(request,reply){
            reply.file('./view/page1.html');
        }
    })
})
```

Please help me solve this problem.Thanks!

Comment: What does the handler for the route "/commit" look like?

Comment: Thanks.I have solved this problem.My input tag lack "name" properyty.